# why $\frac{\partial c(s,t)}{\partial s}=\frac{\nabla f(c(s,t))}{\|\nabla f(c(s,t))\|^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof and I dont understand this part: (reference: [Theorem 2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/local-and-global-extrema-for-functions-of-several-variables/989645BD676BA0F05C76419C4E0326B6))

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $f\in C^1$ with a local minimum at $0$ and no
other critical point.

We may assume that $f(0) = 0.$ For $s > 0$, small, we have a compact
(n — l)-manifold $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: f(x) = s\} = c(s)$. For $s$ and $x$ large possibly, we
extend these level sets by continuity, in fact, if we parametrize $c(s)$ as $c(s, t)$, then

(HERE I DONT KNOW WHY?) (Chain rule? how?)

$$\frac{\partial c(s,t)}{\partial s}=\frac{\nabla f(c(s,t))}{\|\nabla f(c(s,t))\|^2}$$

Comment: What do you know about level sets, manifolds etc?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I only know that the gradient ($\nabla$) is perpendicular to level sets.. but I don't know how can I use this.

Comment: Warning: The formula in the title is not the same than in the text (there is an extra square).

Comment: By definition we have $f(c(s,t))=s$. Assuming sufficient regularity of level sets (which is based on the fact that the gradient of $f$ vanishes only at $0$) you obtain  by differentiating this identity wrt $s$ that $\partial_s c\cdot\nabla f(c(s,t))=1$. Now as you know that gradient is perpendicular to level sets you can show that $\partial_s c$ is parallel to $\nabla f(c(s,t))$ which will give your formula.

Comment: @Emmanuel I   know that gradient is perpendicular to level sets i.e $\nabla f(c(s,t)) \cdot \nabla c(s,t)=0$ Am I right?

Comment: @Emmanuel can you help me with this equation about gradient and perpendicular level sets?

Comment: Take care, $(s,t)\to c(s,t)$ is a vector field from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, indeed $t\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ parametrize the $n-1$ dimensional level sets of $f$. Differentiating $f(c(s,t))=s$ wrt $t_i$ for $i=1,\ldots n-1$ we get $\partial_{t_i}c\cdot \nabla f=0$ thus $\nabla f$ is normal to the tangent hyperplan at $x=c(s,t)$ belonging to the level set $s$ of $f$. Thus it is in the direction of $\partial_s c$ (ie in the direction of $c(s+dx,t)-c(s,t)$ for small $ds$). From $\partial_s c=\lambda \nabla f(c(s,t))$ and $\partial_sc\cdot \nabla f(c(s,t))=1$ stems result.

Comment: @Emmanuel So clear, but now you say  that $\partial_s c=\lambda \nabla f(c(s,t))$ this is by $\partial_{t_i}c\cdot \nabla f=0$ I'm correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for my too quick (and dirty) comments above, this formula is indeed false. As a counter example in dimension $2$, take for instance $f(x,y)=x^2+\frac{y^2}4$ which is $C^1$ with only critical $(0,0)$. Then for $s>0$,
$$C(s)=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R},f(x,y)=s\right\}$$
is an ellipsoid which may be parametrized by
$$c(s,t)=(\sqrt{s}\cos t,2\sqrt{s}\sin t)=\sqrt{s}(\cos t,2\sin t).$$
Then
$\nabla f(x,y)=(2x,\frac y 2)$ and $\nabla f(c(s,t))=\sqrt{s}(2\cos t,\sin t)$, while $\partial_s c=\frac1{2\sqrt{s}}( \cos t, 2\sin t)$ and $\partial_t c=\sqrt{s}(-\sin t,2\cos t)$.
Therefore we have: $\partial_s c\cdot \nabla f(c)=1$, $\partial_t c\cdot \nabla f(c)=0$ BUT $\partial_s c$ is not parallel to $\nabla f(c)$. The announced formula is therefore false, as my silly comments!